# Spring security occasionally redirects to default page instead of pre-login page after successful login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Our team is developing a web application using Spring boot (2.2.2). It uses Spring security to handle the login process. We want the application to redirect back to the page before login (for eg, user access http://example.com/foo/bar -> if login session has expired then show login page -> if login succeeded then directs back to http://example.com/foo/bar)

Everything seems fine except that the application occasionally directs to the default page (for eg, http://example.com) instead of the page before login. When this happens, it seems that the page before login is not saved in the session (according to what my teammate reported). Is this due to our configuration problem?

Following is our WebSecurityConfig

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("...")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("...")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/loginForm")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .usernameParameter("userId")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .failureUrl("/loginForm?error=true")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .invalidSessionUrl("/loginForm")
            ;
    }
```

Since successHandler is not set in WebSecurityConfig, SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler would be called by default. Problem seems occurs in the following part in the **onAuthenticationSuccess** method:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

    if (savedRequest == null) {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        return;
    }
    String targetUrlParameter = getTargetUrlParameter();
    if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()
            || (targetUrlParameter != null && StringUtils.hasText(request
                        .getParameter(targetUrlParameter)))) {
        requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        return;
    }

    clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);

    // Use the DefaultSavedRequest URL
    String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
    logger.debug("Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: " + targetUrl);
    getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
}
```

Occasionally savedRequest is null so Spring security directs to the default page (http://example.com) after successful login. What would be the cause?

Comment: Have you provided any success handler for login? Using `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` might help you achieve what you want. :)

Comment: @DhavalShewale Since successHandler() is not set in the WebSecurityConfig, the default SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler would be called, isn't it? I have edited my question, any further advice is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: My bad, `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` will be called by default if no success handler is specified. The occasional redirection is caused due to `sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/loginForm")`. This is because you are making an explicit call to login page instead of letting spring handle the re-authentication. In my view this should happen always and not occasionally.

Comment: @DhavalShewale Thanks for the advice! :D I commented out the `sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/loginForm")` part and it seems to operate as expected (always directs back to the page before login).

Comment: Great :) Will post it as answer to close the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirection to context root is caused due to `sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/loginForm")`.

This is because you are making an explicit call to login page and hence it is treated as a requested page and not re-direction for authentication. Post authentication, spring would redirect to default url (which is context root by default unless overridden in config).

In my view this should happen always and not occasionally.

Pls remove the mentioned config and let spring handle the re-direction for authentication. :)